# Julia-lang - function testing

Tags: testing, tdd, julia

I am working on a set of functions in Julia and I have to develop a set of covering tests. I have one function that returns 3 values in a tuple.

How can I make a test such as:

```
@test_approx_eq_eps()
```

that will work on all three output values, all of which are floats?

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're asking. Do you want to check if they're approximately equal to each other, or to another 3 values?

Answer (score 2):

Just use a loop in any of it's flavors:

```rb
julia> using Base.Test: @test_approx_eq_eps

julia> ns = tuple(ones(3)...)
(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)

julia> x = 1.0
1.0

julia> epsilon = 0.0
0.0

julia> for n in ns    # simple loop
           @test_approx_eq_eps n x epsilon
       end

julia> [@test_approx_eq_eps(n, x, epsilon) for n in ns]    # comprehension
3-element Array{Void,1}:
 nothing
 nothing
 nothing

julia> foreach(ns) do n    # foreach (doesn't return anything)
           @test_approx_eq_eps n x epsilon
       end

julia> test_aprox_eq_eps(n, x, epsilon) = @test_approx_eq_eps(n, x, epsilon)
test_aprox_eq_eps (generic function with 1 method)

julia> test_aprox_eq_eps.(ns, x, epsilon)    # broadcasting
(nothing, nothing, nothing)
```